# after i add 1 item then delete or update then i reload app data not change

Tags: android

I add,delete and update data but after i add 1 item then delete or update then i reload app data not change

## Database

```
public void deletePrefix(Prefix prefix) {
    Log.i(TAG, "MyDatabaseHelper.delete ... " + prefix.getOldPRe());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_PREFIX, COLUMN_PREFIX_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(prefix.getId())});
    db.close();
}

   public void updatePrefix(Prefix prefix) {
    Log.i(TAG, "MyDatabaseHelper.updatePrefix ... " + prefix.getOldPRe());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PREFIX_ID,prefix.getId());
    values.put(COLUMN_PREFIX_OLD, prefix.getOldPRe());
    values.put(COLUMN_PREFIX_NEW, prefix.getNewPre());

    db.update(TABLE_PREFIX, values, COLUMN_PREFIX_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(prefix.getId())});
    db.close();

}
```

## Acitivity

```
db.addPrefix(prefix);
                prefixList.add(prefix);
                initializeRCV();
 db.updatePrefix(prefix);
                prefixList.remove(pos);
                prefixList.add(pos, prefix);
                initializeRCV();
db.deletePrefix(prefixList.get(position));
            prefixList.remove(position);
            initializeRCV();
```

somtime reload app data is change but sometime it not active

Comment: Is it not because it should be "?s". [See documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

Comment: Check that `db.delete` returns a value > 0. If it not the case, nothing has changed

Comment: int deletedSuccess=db.delete(TABLE_PREFIX, COLUMN_PREFIX_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(prefix.getId())});  .... Log this "deletedSuccess"